# undelete records using java code?

Tags: apex, java

Hi while i am saving this code getting error:

```
public class deletetion{
public void undeleteRecords() {
   try {

      QueryResult qResult = connection
            .queryAll('SELECT Id, SystemModstamp FROM '
                  + 'Account WHERE IsDeleted=true'
                  +'ORDER BY SystemModstamp DESC LIMIT 5');

      String[] Ids = new String[qResult.getSize()];

      for (int i = 0; i < qResult.getSize(); i++) {
         Ids[i] = qResult.getRecords()[i].getId();
      }


      UndeleteResult[] undelResults = connection.undelete(Ids);


      for (UndeleteResult result : undelResults) {
         if (result.isSuccess()) {
            System.debug('Undeleted Account ID: ' + result.getId());
         } else {
            if (result.getErrors().length > 0) {
               System.debug('Error message: '
                     + result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
            }
         }
      }
   } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
      ce.printStackTrace();
   }
}


}
```

error:

```
Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: QueryResult at line 6 column 7
Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: UndeleteResult at line 15 column 7
```

could you please help on this.

Comment: Can you please include the error text?

Comment: This is not Apex Code. Java, maybe? Can you please tag this question correctly? If you're trying to do this in actual Apex Code, you're doing it wrong. This looks more like what you'd do in Java.

Comment: yes i am using java code how can we save java code in salesforce.

Comment: @user123 You don't write Java in salesforce. You use Apex Code. It looks like Java, but it's not. See the example I just added to my answer for how I might write a rough draft of this code in Apex Code. You just need to learn how to translate from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error in the query because there's no space between `true` and `ORDER` in your statement:

```
... WHERE IsDeleted=true'+'ORDER BY ...
                ... is intepreted as ...
... WHERE IsDeleted=trueORDER BY ...
```

So, you simply need to add a space after after true or before ORDER.

---

Edit: From your compilation errors, assuming you're trying to write Apex Code, you're actually copying from a *Java* code sample with some apparent Apex Code thrown in for good measure. In Apex Code, you'd write your class like this:

```
public class deletetion{
    public void undeleteRecords() {
        Id[] ids = new List<Id>(
            new Map<Id, Account>(
                [
                    SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE
                    ORDER BY SystemModStamp DESC LIMIT 5 ALL ROWS
                ]
            ).keySet()
        );
        for(Database.UndeleteResult result: Database.undelete(ids, false)) {
            if(result.isSuccess()) {
                System.debug('Undeleted Account Id: '+result.getId());
            } else {
                System.debug('Failed to restore Account Id: '+result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```